# Can't save changes

Tags: password

I'm brand new to Ubuntu. I downloaded with Wubi and 13.04 shares my computer with Windows 7, (which hopefully will be deleted soon. Goodbye, Bill).

First, can I toggle back and forth between Win7 and Ubuntu without shutting down and restarting my computer?
And second, Ubuntu doesn't appear to be saving any of my changes. I unlocked several icons from the tool bar, added my own wall paper, and typed and saved a LibreOffice document to the Documents Folder, and then saved the document to a flash drive. After shutting down, all these changes were lost and there was nothing saved to the flash drive either. And I don't believe Ubuntu saved my password. I have to log on as a Guest.
The other odd thing that I noticed, before I installed Ubuntu I got a warning that there was a previous version on the computer and it would be uninstalled. This is a new computer (4 weeks), and it's only ever had Win7. So I'm not sure what that's all about.

What am I missing here?

Thanks for your help,
Bry

Comment: You wrote "13.04". Sorry, but 13.04 is outdated and not supported. Please try a supported version from [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop).

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't toggle without restarting - although you can look into virtual machines - they'll provide a way to run one as your full desktop and one virtually in a window (at the cost of a bit of performance).

Have you *installed* Ubuntu to the hard disk? *Only then it will save changes*. The other mode, the Live mode ('Try Ubuntu') is an environment where (unless you specify space for storage when creating the USB) all changes are undone upon shutdown.

Comment: Thank you for getting back to me. Yes, I downloaded to the harddrive. One other thin I noticed upon booting up: I get the message mount:/prsc/mounts: no such file... Is there a repair utility? Thank you.

Comment: By 'downloaded', do you mean you downloaded the Ubuntu ISO file? Or did you go through the USB's 'Install Ubuntu' wizard?

Comment: I downloaded Wubi from the CNET site. It took about 6 hours over a 2 day period to get what I got. I don't have a disc drive. Can I up-grade without having to go through the whole process again? Thank you... Bry

Comment: @bcripps Yes, use the 'Software Updater' app. P.S. Wubi installation is now deprecated and unsupported.

Comment: Where do I find this "Software Updater"?

Comment: Search in the Dash.

Comment: @bcripps Forget the version you downloaded with an old Wubi version. It downloaded a buggy development version of 13.04. This version doesn't create an user account. If you want to delete Windows, Wubi is definitively the wrong way. If I missunderstood you, see [Wubi info](http://askubuntu.com/tags/wubi/info).

Comment: Come on. I'm new to this. What the heck id a DASH?

Comment: @bcripps The thing you get when you click on the Ubuntu icon in the task-bar.

Answer (score 1):

You installed an old and outdated Wubi version which downloaded a broken version of 13.04. This version doesn't create an user account. So it is not possible to login with your user.

It makes no sense to repair this broken version because 13.04 is now unsupported and upgrades from 13.04 to the next supported version 14.04 are not faster than a fresh install.

Please try a supported Ubuntu version from [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop) or if you need a smaller image to reduce download time, probably Lubuntu is a good choice for you. see [here](http://lubuntu.net). In general, use .iso and not .torrent downloads because .torrent downloads are slower.

After downloading copy iso file with [Rufus](https://rufus.akeo.ie) to a pendrive and boot into pendrive to install Ubuntu.

If you still think you need Wubi, copy iso file and wubi.exe in the same folder and run wubi.exe. This should avoid time consuming downloads. For newer Ubuntu versions and/or Windows versions [community supported versions](https://github.com/hakuna-m/wubiuefi/wiki#releases) work only. see [wubi info](https://askubuntu.com/tags/wubi/info)

Comment: ngng, IMHO, you are right. The password issues of 13.04 are old Wubi bugs: [bug 1155704](https://bugs.launchpad.net/wubi/+bug/1155704) and [bug 1152708](https://bugs.launchpad.net/wubi/+bug/1152708)

Comment: Ok, I read about Lubuntu and it seems right for my notebook with only 4 gigs of RAM. Now to I uninstall what I have now? How? And I don't have a pendrive (is that a flashdrive stick?) And I don't have a disc burner or player. I need to download direct to the hard drive and I would like to keep Win 7 active for a week or two while I sort things out. Possible? And thank you all... Bry

Comment: Opps. Sorry about that. The second line should read: "Now, do I need to uninstall what I have now...."

Comment: @bcripps I am not an expert for English words, but flashdrive stick and pendrives should be the same.

Comment: @bcripps If you need the space, you should uninstall it. If you use Wubi again, it uninstalls Ubuntu automatically. If you  don't use it again, see [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide#Uninstallation)

Comment: @bcripps Wubi does not delete Windows. So it is possible to keep Windows 7. But it is easier to delete Windows if you don't use Wubi because Wubi uses the Windows boot menu and installs Ubuntu on a Windows partition.

Comment: ngng... you English is great! And thank you for all your help...

Comment: I'm not sure I got an answer to my question. Can I download Lubuntu and still have my Win 7 for a few weeks. And how do I go about this? I plan to delete what I now have and start fresh. Thank you... Bry

Comment: @bcripps 1) You can download Lubuntu.  If it is a new computer, it should have a 64 bit CPU. So currently, I would download [Lubuntu 14.04.4 64 bit](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/lubuntu/releases/14.04/release/lubuntu-14.04.4-desktop-amd64.iso). 2) If you have no  pendrives, external USB drives, DVDs etc, you can download a community supported Wubi version from [here](https://github.com/hakuna-m/wubiuefi/releases/download/14044r302/wubi14044r302.exe).  3) If you run wubi14044r302.exe in the same folder as iso, no downloads should be needed. 4) Wubi doesn't delete Windows.

Comment: 5) If you want to delete Windows. [Migrate Wubi](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MigrateWubi) to real partitions and then delete Windows and your Wubi install. This is more difficult than deleting Windows, if you don't use Wubi, but possible.

Comment: Okay. Got Lubuntu... it's a lot different. No Desktop Icons. One last question and I'll leave you alone... I work out of a small bar that has password protected wifi.... Where in Foxfire do I enter that password? Thank you, Bry

Comment: For a wifi connection you should use the Network Manager. see [here](http://lubuntuhowto.blogspot.co.at/2014/06/wifi-network-manager-missing-on-lubuntu-1404.html). If you are connected, you can use Firefox. It is similar to Windows.

Comment: @bcripps Network Manager is the same as on Ubuntu. But you are right. Lubuntu dektop is a little bit different. But it has a smaller download image and it should be faster than Ubuntu on older computers.

Comment: Why is Windows so simple? Type in the password and I'm on line.

No where on Lbuntu Network Connections do I see “Enter Password” Where is it?

And what is Connection Name? SSID? BSIDD? And MAC Address?

The guy behind the bar speaks Spanish, I speak English. So there's no help there.

Come on guys. I'm new to this. No more acronyms, please.

I appreciate the help but if the folks in S. Africa want people to use Ubuntu or Lbuntu... they better hire a guy in marketing that can dicier all this computer jargon and make it accessible to normal folks like me.

Thanks for the help, once again.
Bry

Comment: Scrap Lubuntu. How do I load Ubuntu without a disc drive?

Comment: In my case, it is simple like Windows. The first time I had to click on the network manager icon in system tray, to select my wifi network and to enter my password and after that it connects automatically if my wifi network is available. That's it. I am not sure, if your issue is that the network manager icon is not  available or  if your issue is that your wifi hardware doesn't work with 14.04. If your hardware doesn't work with 14.04 it doesn't make sense to download Ubuntu because it uses the same drivers.

Comment: @bcripps If your issue is that your network manager icon is not available, press ALT and F2 simultaneously. A small window should open and you can type:  `nm-applet` which should run the network manager icon in the system tray.

Comment: @bcripps If you think that your issue is Lubuntu: The download link for Ubuntu 14.04.4 64 bit is [here](http://releases.ubuntu.com/trusty/ubuntu-14.04.4-desktop-amd64.iso).  The installation procedure is the same as for Lubuntu.

Comment: When I followed your link, this is what I got... If you are using lubuntu 14.04 trusty, you will noticed that the WiFi icon/ network manager is missing.

The WiFi icon / network manager should be on right side of the desktop panel, but instead there is a keyboard icon.

This is a bug on lubuntu 14.04, luckily even without the WiFi icon/ network manager you still can connect to WiFi hotspot manually... I can't believe they would release Lubutu with a bug. At least fix it....

Comment: And the link download link you provided for Ubuntu 14.04 doesn't appear to work.

Comment: Oh, and ngng... thanks for all this. After dealing with me you are probably wishing you never got involved with the forum...

Comment: Sorry ngng. The link is working. I just get any notification that the program was downloading. Thanks again... Bry

Comment: @bcripps IMHO the network manager bug of Lubuntu has been fixed. I only gave you the link because the article shows where you can store your password and how you can run network manager setup from start menu.

Comment: Thanks ngng... I dumped Lubuntu and installed Ubuntu 14. something or other. I read about connecting to a WiFi hotspot and it referred me the the menu bar, (whatever that is). I got icons down the left hand side of the screen and that's all. Now... I'm in a little bar in the DR. The guy behind the counter does not speak English. He does not know what a router is. All he can give me is a password which works fine if I enter it into Windows 7. Now, how do I do the same thing with Ubuntu? Where do I enter the password without all the other SSDS stuff? How do I access the internet?

Comment: If your network manager doesn't display any wifi hotspots, you need an additional wifi driver. [Here](http://www.pcworld.com/article/2455972/how-to-fix-your-internet-connection-in-ubuntu-linux.html) are some pictures of the network manger. So if some wifi hotspots are available, you will find it. Otherwise you need an additional driver.  To find your driver, you can type in a terminal `lspci -nn | grep -i net` (I also was googling that command). The output should show a number in [ ] with : in the middle. It is the important number for google or for asking in a forum.

Comment: @bcripps If you give me some information about your computer, I will google your wifi hardware.

Comment: Hi ngng: I know you must be as frustrated as I am; thanks for hanging in. You keep talking about this Internet Manager. I don't see it listed anywhere. Where do I find it? Other than not being able to connect to a wifi hotspot, everything is working well.

Comment: @bcripps As I wrote in a previous comment for Lubuntu: press ALT and F2 simultaneously. A small window should open and you can type: `nm-applet` . Press return to confirm the command. An additional network manager icon should appear and then run network manager by clicking on the icon.

Comment: @bcripps But network manager icon should still exist and it doesn't help to run network manager icon if you need an additonal wifi driver.

Comment: Sorry for delay. Wifi bar is closed on Wed. Pressing ALT and F2 simultaneously does nothing but bring up a fluttering Audio Speaker icon.What's this Icon in the upper right hand side of the screen; looks like a windshield wiper? It has something to do with internet connections. Bry

Comment: Computer is brand new, Lenovo 11e. AMD A4-6210 APU with AMD Radeon R3 Graphics.
Four gigs of RAM. 64-bit operating system. Win7 installed.

Comment: @bcripps the "windshield wiper" is the icon for the network manager . Lenovo 11e uses function keys for vendor specific functions. If you want to use F2 as I use it, you can disable these functions or press Fn and F2. see [here](https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/ThinkPad-11e-Windows-E-and-Edge/How-to-disable-Fn-key-requirement-for-function-keys-F1-F2-etc/td-p/462719)

Comment: @bcripps I googled your hardware. Probably, you need an additional broadcom wifi driver. Download these packages: [dkms](http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/d/dkms/dkms_2.2.0.3-1.1ubuntu5.14.04.5_all.deb) and [broadcom](http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/multiverse/b/broadcom-sta/broadcom-sta-dkms_6.30.223.271-2_all.deb) on Windows. On Ubuntu type in a terminal: `cd /host/Users/*/Downloads` and `sudo dpkg -i *dkms*.deb` to install it. The path /host/Users/*/Downloads only works if you install on C:.But I recommend that you ask a new question with your wifi problem for better support.

Comment: Ok- I click the windshield icon and I get three choices: Option # 1: VPN Connections and an option to configure VPN- click on that and I get a window that says Ethernet and an “ADD” button.

Comment: Option #2: Enable Networking. Chick on that and I get “Disconnected.”

Comment: Option #3: Edit Connections – click on that and get I get Ethernet, Wired connection 1. And the “ADD” button.

Ok. Can you walk me through this maze? Just get me connected to the internet, please! Thanks, ngng... Bry

Comment: @bcripps VPN, Ethernet, Wired Connection are the wrong things. If you don't see "Wi-Fi" like [here](http://www.pcworld.com/article/2455972/how-to-fix-your-internet-connection-in-ubuntu-linux.html) you need a wifi driver.